# Node.js node_modules interfering with each other

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a weird problem with Node.js where node_module directories seem to be interfering with each other. I have the following file structure:

```
- node_modules
- User.js
- app
  - app.js
  - node_modules
```

So I have a node_modules in the top level directory as well as one inside the app directory. Each node_modules directory contains just a mongoose directory. The User.js file is a simple mongoose model:

```
exports.User = function() {
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var UserSchema = new Schema({
        email:      { type: String },
        firstName:  { type: String },
        lastName:   { type: String },
    });

    mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
    var User = mongoose.model("User");
    return User;
}();
```

The main app, app.js, looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/crnapi");
require("../User").User.find(function(err, users) {
    if(err)
        console.log(err);

    console.log("here");
});
```

Nothing but connecting to mongo and finding a user. The problem I'm seeing is that the call to find() just hangs--the callback is never called.

However, if I remove inner node_modules directory (the one inside the app folder), it works fine. It's like the presence of the inner node_modules somehow screws up the workings of mongoose. I know I could put everything in the outer node_modules and just delete the inner one, but there are reasons for me to not do that.

Can anyone tell me what is going on here? Is there an debug mode I can run node or mongoose in that will tell me what it's getting hung up on?

Comment: Something just occurred to me. Is it possible that two separate instances of mongoose are being created and used? The app.js one would use the one from the inner node_modules and User.js would use the one from the outer node_modules. Maybe I have two separate connections to mongodb running?

Comment: You're right, you'll get two separate instances of Mongoose. The one your loading into your "User.js" module probably never gets a connection. Because of that, the query just gets queued (that's default Mongoose behavior). If you want to hold onto your current structure (not sure why you want two node_modules directories) you could make a module who's sole job is to return a mongoose object (and perhaps call connect on it as well).

Comment: Read http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders to see how requiring a "named" module (i.e., not a relative path) works.

Comment: Actually, I think it could work "as is" if you ensure there's no mongoose module in your app/node_modules directory.

Comment: Thanks guys, that does seem to be the issue. If I take the mongoose.connect() call out of app.js and move it into User.js so app.js has no mongoose anything, it works. I'll probably just move the mongoose stuff up to the highest global node_modules directory. That should get all modules using the same one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was creating multiple instances of mongoose instead of creating a single one and having all the code use it. I solved this by moving the mongoose module into a high enough directory that all the code that uses mongoose could get access to the same one.